# SignalR java: client-test-integration-android : InvalidHttpStatusCodeException

Tags: java, signalr

I am trying to run the signalR self-host example server ( http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/deployment/tutorial-signalr-self-host ) with the android test integration (provided with the signalr official java client). I have tested that the self-host server is accessible by clients written in C# from another machine in the local network (I changed localhost to * on the server). However, I have not been successful yet in connection from android. I get the following error:

> Critical: AutomaticTransport - Error:
>   microsoft.aspnet.signalr.client.http.InvalidHttpStatusCodeException:
>   Invalid status code: 500

The full log can be seen here:

http://pastebin.com/fMPabbN1

Am I missing something? It does not look like a compilation or IP configuration error. If I don't run the server and run the tests, I get socketTimeOut, which is expected.

I ran the "Basic Connection Flow - Auto" test.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Adding to my answer in case someone else runs into it. It was a crappy mistake on my part, jumped into java client without understanding signalr properly! The Hub class on the server and the Hub proxy name has to be the same. So on the server side the class:

> public class MessageHub : Hub

And on the client side

> HubProxy hub = connection.createHubProxy( “MessageHub” );

And voila!